# html pass a link with get parameters within a link

Tags: html, parameters

I am trying to pass a link within another in such a way :

http://www.1st_site.com/?u=http://www.2nd_site.com/?parameter1=xyz

I think what the problem is , parameter1=xyz is passed as a parameter for 1st_site

is there anyway to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the entire URL which is represented as query parameter value, else it will be interpreted as part of the request URL, thus this part: `http://www.2nd_site.com/?parameter1=xyz`.

It's unclear what programming language you're using, but most of decent webbased languages provides functions/methods/classes to achieve this, e.g. `URLEncoder` in Java, or `c:url` and `c:param` in JSP/JSTL, `urlencode()` in PHP and `escape()` in JavaScript.

Here's at least an online URL encoder: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/. If you input `http://www.2nd_site.com/?parameter1=xyz`, you should get `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.2nd_site.com%2F%3Fparameter1%3Dxyz` back so the request URL should effectively end up in:

http://www.1st_site.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.2nd_site.com%2F%3Fparameter1%3Dxyz

Comment: thank you for your help. I am using php so I do encode it using urlencode.
the reason for trying this mess is to get facebook share to recognize a link with parameters in it....which it seems to dislike...I did try to encode the url but that didnt seem to do it...any suggestions?